# Merge duplicate rows excel

Tags: excel, bash, excel-2010

Right now I have a bunch of rows with data from different sources. Column A contains the name of the source file and the rest of the columns are and assortment of values pulled from those sources.

What I would like to do is combined the rows with the same source file.

Currently:

> Source1 , value1, value2, value3
>
> Source1 , value4, value 5
>
> Source2 , value 1, value 2
>
> Source2 , value 3, value 4

What I need it to look like

> Source1 , value1,value2,value3,value4,value5
>
> Source2, value1,value2,value3,value4

I'm flexible with how i go about doing this. if its easier to export to csv and work with it In bash rather than doing it in excel I can do that

Comment: If you're feeling really adventurous, in data analysis, this is called changing long data to wide data, or "reshaping" data.  Certainly not the fastest way to go about it (learning some stats/data package like R first) but well, there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I think this just about does it in awk, but I have to feed the kids :-):

```
awk -F, '{if(!length(d[$1]))d[$1]=$1;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)d[$1]=d[$1]","$i}END{for(i in d)print d[i]}' yourfile.csv
```

Output:

```
Source1 , value1, value2, value3, value4, value 5
Source2 , value 1, value 2, value 3, value 4
```

The output lines are going to be stored in array d[]. As each line is read, I check to see if array element d[] indexed by the first field on the line is undefined (i.e. length=0), if it is undefined I store field one in there (i.e. the source). Then I concatenate all the remaining fields in the line onto the string I have stored. At the end, I print out all the strings in d[].